# Websdriver chrome issue

Tags: typescript, selenium-chromedriver, wdio

i'm currently running tests using typescript and getting a rather annoying error.

This is the error I get:

'2023-11-13T17:05:52.084Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to unknown error: unknown error: result.webdriverValue.value list is missing or empty in Runtime.callFunctionOn response (Session info: chrome=119.0.6045.124)'

I am using chrome version 119.0.6045.124 and my chromedriver is 119.0.6045.105 within my selenium grid path as per usual. I had the same issue last week and I just updated my chromedriver to 119 which resolved it, but now it's seemingly back again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Tried to run some tests using my usual method with selenium grid. The webpage opens and fails with the error message.